# How to access the element at an index in a structure in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, data-structures

When you have a structure that contains an array and the length of the array, how do you access specific indexes of the array?

I defined my structure as:

```
struct intqq {
    int a[0];
    int len;
};
```

So how would I access a specific element in the array in the structure?

Comment: Do you need to do this in C? It's much easier (and safer) in C++ with the STL.

Comment: Yes, I'm working with C for this specific problem

Comment: You need to put the array at the end of the structure.

Comment: I think the original version of your problem showed your question much more clearly than this one.

Comment: You no longer need the ability to resize the array (post-edit)?

Comment: Your array is length zero, no matter what. There is no way to access the elements, since there are no elements.

Comment: @tweej: Do not tell posters to use a different language. C is fine.

Comment: @Olaf Read again. I didn't. I asked.

Comment: A zero-length array is undefined behaviour in C. Your compiler should complain. If that is gcc (which accepts this as an extension), enable warnings and use `-std=c11` or `c99`. Then read about _flexible array members_.

Comment: I'm trying to call a specific element of the array in a seperate function, but I dont know how to access that element/index from the array that is inside the structure my function consumes

Comment: How are you attempting to pass the structure to the function?

Comment: @ShagunChhikara You need to put the empty array at the end of the structure. That is [struct hack tricks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/struct-hack/)

Answer (score 0):

The conventional way to handle this is to keep the array and the length separate from each other, and to pass them both to whatever function needs them.  That also gives you the freedom to declare arrays with a static size or dynamically via malloc.

Answer (score 0):

For this zero-length array to work, you need to put the array as the `last member` of the struct, not the first one. Then should be able to access the index as usual.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    typedef struct {
        int x;
        int y[];
    } flex;

    int len = 10;
    flex *f1 = malloc( sizeof( flex ) + sizeof( int ) * len );

    f1->x = len;
    f1->y[0] = 1;
    f1->y[1] = 2;
    printf ( "y[1] = %d\n", f1->y[1] );
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a bunch of compiling errors even when I do that

Comment: Can you copy the command that you used to compile, and also the error messages?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Declaring `flex f1;` doesn't actually allocate any space in the flexible array member.

Comment: yeah my bad - how does it look now?